# Accessing dbconfig file through class - PHP

Tags: php

I would like to insert data to the database for which I have a class called InsertTodb. But I am unable to access $dbc variable (which is in dbconfig .php) through class. Here is the code

My Class File

```
<?php
require("dbconfig.php");
class InsertTodb {
    public $tableNme;
    public $data1;
    public $data2;
    public $data3;
    public $arg1;
    public $arg2;
    public $arg3;


    function insertData($tableName, $data1, $data2, $data3, $val1, $val2, $val3) {
        $this->tableNme = $tableName;       
        $this->data1 = $data1;
        $this->data2 = $data2;
        $this->data3 = $data3;
        $this->arg1 = $val1;        
        $this->arg2 = $val2;        
        $this->arg3 = $val3;        

        $insquery = "insert into ".$this->tableNme."(".$this->data1.", ".$this->data2.", ".$this->data3.") values('".$this->arg1."', '".$this->arg2."',' ".$this->arg3."')";
        echo $insquery; 

        if(mysqli_query($dbc, $insquery)) {                 
        $success = "Product added successfully."; 
        echo $success; 
        }
        else {
        $failed = "Error adding product."; 
        echo $failed; 
        }
}
}
?>
```

My dbconfig file

```
<?php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'oop';

$dbc1 = mysqli_connect ($db_hostname,$db_username, $db_password,$db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Could not establish database connection!";
exit();
}
?>
```

My code

```
<?php

include "InsertTOdb.php";

$ins = new InsertTodb();

$ins->insertData("tableone", "name", "age", "desig",  "Guru", "25", "Accountant");

?>
```

When I run the above program, it shows the error "Notice: Undefined variable: dbc" and ..." Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ...". I am new to OOP. Please help to fix it.

Comment: "But I am unable to access $dbc variable..". In fact the resource variable is  named $dbc**1** ($dbc1 = mysqli_connect ($db_hostname,$db_username, $db_password,$db_name);).

Comment: add `global $dbc1` in your insert function

Comment: Please avoid using global vars, that's really the opposite of good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor your code a little. First of all,

```
<?php
include "dbconfig.php"; // Add this first.
include "InsertTOdb.php";
$ins = new InsertTodb($dbc1); // Feed the connector to your class.
$ins->insertData("tableone", "name", "age", "desig",  "Guru", "25", "Accountant");
?>
```

Now change the InsertTOdb class a little:

```
class InsertTodb {
    private $dbc;
    public function __construct($dbc) {
        $this->dbc = $dbc;
    }

    // ... the rest of class's properties ...
    function insertData($tableName, $data1, $data2, $data3, $val1, $val2, $val3) {
        ...
        // Change $dbc to $this->dbc.
        if(mysqli_query($this->dbc, $insquery)) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Your `insertData()` looks a bit clunky with all these $data1, $data2 etc. values (you should pass them all at once as arrays or objects), but this should be enough for now.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, it works fine now. Yeah I will do it with array. I am going gradually. I wanted to check if this basic code works.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the database handle to the constructor of you class like this:

```
class InsertTodb {
  // Define property to store $dbc
  protected $dbc;

  public function __construct($dbc) {
    $this->dbc = $dbc;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Inside of your `InsertTodb` class access the database handle via `$this->dbc`, e.g. `mysqli_query($this->dbc, $insquery)`.

In your code you have to pass `$dbc1`to your newly created object:

```
$ins = new InsertTodb($dbc1);
```